# Where may I find references to Maa Durga's arrival and departure vehicle?

Tags: durga, reference-request

I have heard Maa Durga's arrival and departure vehicle (like horse, elephant, palanquin) depends on the days of the week when the festival starts and ends. And there is a significance of any such vehicle.

Where may I find references to Maa Durga's arrival and departure vehicle?

Comment: Mount of Bhagavati Durga Devi is Lion...

Comment: @Tezz okay. Vehicle seems a more appropriate word. Edited the question.

Comment: This year Durga Devi arrives on horse (Ghotake agaman) as written in Bengali Panjika.@SeverusSnape

Comment: @Rickross Yes. I am wondering the basis of this rule. Is it based on astrology or any event relevant to Maa Durga?

Comment: Yes, there must be some basis. I would also like to know that.@SeverusSnape